# Refer to external variables in Laravel eloquent whereHas method

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

The following code gives the error **Undefined variable searchParam**. Need help.

```
if($searchParam!=null){
        $results=Image::whereHas('subjects',function($q){
            $q->where('subject','LIKE','%'.$searchParam.'%');
        });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try with -

```
$results=Image::whereHas('subjects',function($q) use ($searchParam){
     $q->where('subject','LIKE','%'.$searchParam.'%');
});
```